# CSS bug on pull menu jQuery script

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know my question is a bit too specific, but I cannot solve the problem.

Here's my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NWMST/
(You'll see CSS has some comments, you can ignore some stuff...)

**THE PROBLEM:** notice tht the menu by default, has rounded corners (border-radius). When you click it to pull the menu out, the two top corners stop having the border-radius. However, if you click again, to close it, the top corners remain the same, with no border radius...

I've done many different tries with snippets I found here at stackoverflow, but non where the solution I am looking for. I'm sorry for asking this, I understand jQuery only to manipulate it, but I can barely program my own scripts.

The pull tutorial I used: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/

Here's the markup, styles and scripting (however, you can see it live in the demo to actually see what the problem is):

HTML MARKUP:

```
<nav id="menu" class="clearfix">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a class="current first-item" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
#menu a {text-decoration: none; }
#menu ul {display: none; }
#menu {text-align: center; }

#menu #pull {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font: 700 19px/1.45em 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  padding: 8px 0 6px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc4c7;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* the rule I'm using on the script */
#menu #pull.radius {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

#menu #pull i {
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#menu #pull:hover,
#menu #pull:focus,
#menu #pull:active {color: #04bfee; }

#menu {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

#menu li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font: 700 12px/1em 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  padding: 8px 12px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #bdc4c7;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#menu li a.current,#menu li a:hover,#menu li a:focus {
  color: #0abcff;
  border: 0 none;
  border: 1px solid #bdc4c7;
  border-bottom: 0 none;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

#menu li a.first-item {
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}
```

JQUERY SCRIPT:

```
  $(function() {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('#menu ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();
    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
      if($(this).is('.radius')) {$(this).removeClass('radius');}
      $(this).addClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
      e.preventDefault();
      menu.slideToggle();
    });
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $(window).width();
    if(w > 767 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
      menu.removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
```

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ok: http://jsfiddle.net/NWMST/6/ ? 
Just replace this:

```
  if($(this).is('.radius')) {$(this).removeClass('radius');}
  $(this).addClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
```

with this:

```
  $(this).toggleClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I tried something similar, I deleted the if, but I didn't change the add with toggle... Amazing how a little word can change the whole thing! Thanks and great answer

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of errors in your Javascript.
Change:

```
  if($(this).is('.radius')) {$(this).removeClass('radius');}
  $(this).addClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
```

to

```
    if($(this).hasClass('radius')){
        $(this).removeClass('radius');
    }
    else{  
      $(this).addClass('radius').siblings().removeClass('radius');
    }
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/NWMST/4/

Your mistakes:

1. Check if element has a class with `hasClass("radius")` instead of `is(".radius")`
2. Always adding the class radius to the pull element

Comment: Great answer, I thumbed it up. i choose Cherniv's only because it's more compressed! But great anyways! Greetings from Argentina, Santz

Answer (score 1):

Use this JavaScript:

```
  $(function() {
   menu = $('#menu ul');
   menuHeight = menu.height();
   $('#pull').cklick(function() {
    menu.slideToggle();
    $('#pull').toggle(function() {
      $('#pull').animate({
        border-top-left-radius: '3px',
        border-top-right-radius: '3px'
      }, slow);
    }, function() {
      $('#pull').animate({
        border-top-left-radius: '0',
        border-top-right-radius: '0'
      }, slow);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
#menu #pull.radius{border-radius:3px;}
```